# Superset datasets queries

Tags: apache-superset

I have deployed superset using the helm chart. I brought in my Redis but looks like still, it's pointing to a wrong Redis host. I have confirmed REDIS_HOST is set to point to my external Redis.

I'm getting the following error when I run datasets queries.

`Error -2 connecting to redis:6379. Name or service not known.`

Any idea what the issue is?

Answer (score 0):

I was wrongly passing the Redis URL. I defined it without the /port and redis:, and this worked